# How can I setup a Mail Transfer Agent?

Tags: email, cron-jobs

I intend to use `mutt` to send automated emails via `cron` or `at` with attachments to my gmail address when particular events happen on my Ubuntu server.  Currently, `mutt` cannot send email to external email addresses, I believe this is because I need to setup a Mail Transfer Agent.  How do I go about selecting a suitable MTA and how do I set it up to perform what I need it to do?

Comment: You don't need mutt to have cron or at send mails to your gmail-account.  Any properly configured MTA should be enough for that.

Comment: I need to be able to include attachments with the outgoing mail so I thought I would need mutt for that.

Comment: This is an important question. Lots of us set up Linux servers and need some way to mail out events and reports. In many (most!) cases, a full-blown mail server is overkill. I learned that recently setting up Postfix for such a task. I should have set up a send-only tool like one of these, and I will in the future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few choices to be made when selecting an MTA to install;
the first one is whether you want a *send-only* MTA or you need a
fully-fledged mail server.

[This Unix.SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server)
provides a comprehensive list of send-only MTAs available; all of them
are already packaged for Ubuntu 10.10. There are a few things you
might want to consider when choosing a send-only MTA:

1. whether it can queue e-mails for later delivery in case of a
   failure: IIRC, only `nullmailer` can do this.
2. whether it will replace the system mail delivery agent (look for a
   line `Provides: mail-transport-agent` in the output of `apt-cache
   show package`).  If it does, then all mail originating from the
   system (including reports from cron jobs, popularity statistics,
   etc.) will be handled by the MTA you install: if you do not set up
   correct mail aliases for *root* and other users, the email might
   end up delivered at the wrong address (typically, some sysadmin at
   your ISP).  Currently, packages `nullmailer`, `esmtp-run` (but not
   `esmtp`) and `ssmtp` fall into this category.
3. All send-only MTAs will just forward your email to another server
   (called "relay host" or "smarthost"; typically it's your ISP's SMTP
   server) and then let it handle all the details of real Internet
   mail delivery.  You need to figure out whether there are any
   special requirements for connecting to the ISP server (e.g., some
   kind of authentication or TLS) and choose an MTA that supports the
   required features (for instance, `ssmtp` does not support any kind
   of authentication or SSL/TLS).

Fully-fledged mail servers include [exim](http://www.exim.org),
[postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), and
[sendmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail).  The
post-installation installation script for Debian/Ubuntu will do a
great job of producing a working configuration for some common setup
(delivery of mail to the local system only; sending email through a
"smarthost" -- i.e., a mail server you funnel all your emails
through, typically your ISP's SMTP host; internet site with full
inbound and outbound connectivity).  IMHO, postfix is the easiest to
run and configure, but since it's so capable, its configuration manual
is way longer than any of the send-only MTAs.

In addition, the *real* risk with setting up a mail server is that, if
you make a mistake in the local configuration, you end up with mail
delivered to the wrong place (read: lost) or *-worse-* with an
open-relay system that can be used by spammers (and, trust me, they
can find an open relay before you realize your server is one).

My advice would be then to start with a send-only MTA and then
upgrade to a full mail server only if you see the need for it (which
is not the case if you just want to send emails to your GMail
address).

Comment: OK, so lets say I setup an email address like myserver@gmail.com and enable smtp on the gmail account.  I could configure a client program on the server to send mail using this gmail account via SMTP and therefore avoid the complexity of a fully fledged mail server setup?

Comment: @Griffo: Yes, this is exactly what a "send-only" MTA does; just use `msmtp` (as suggested in ixtmixilix' answer) or choose one from the list at the URL I have posted above.

Comment: +1 for nullmailer... I use it on my servers, and it's very convenient. Very lightweight, relatively easy to setup. And once it works, you just don't have to bother about it anymore :)

Comment: Also mda (The DragonFly Mail Agent) is able to queue emails for later delivery.

Comment: It's dma, not mda (The DragonFly Mail Agent).

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend `msmtp`. Setting up other mail systems, such as `sendmail`, is definitely quite a hassle. Once you have `msmtp` setup, you can use it with `mutt`, and you can also masquerade it as `sendmail` so that programs won't know the difference between the two MTAs. Full details available on [the website.](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

The links below provides all the MTA choices you can choose, according to your Ubuntu version:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mail-transport-agent (for 12.04)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mail-transport-agent (for 14.04)

Personally, I found that `ssmtp` is very easy to setup and run, just 2 commands will do:

```
$ sudo aptitude install mailutils ssmtp
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssmtp
```

Comment: According to the ArchLinux wiki, [ssmtp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) is no longer maintained and they recommend [msmtp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp).